# Firebase Google authentication JavaScript network error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have written a chrome extension that uses firebase Google authentication with firebaseui.  It's been working great except on one specific clients network.  It seems like a firewall issue. You can see the error in the console here.  Client has whitelisted the following domains

```
www.gstatic.com/ 
*.firebaseio.com
www.googleapis.com 
apis.google.com 
cdn.firebase.com 
*.firebaseapp.com
```

[image]

Comment: Client tried off the network filter and it works, so for sure a problem with filter  Are all the domains listed here that should be whitelisted?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include errors as *text*, not images. Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)